# Why isn't simplecart.js not working for me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I don't understand why this simple cart is not working for me. The markup seems to be fine and everything and it works on jsfiddle. However, in my editor (aptanastudio3) it does not,  and it's what I'm using to build the site simplecart.js will be implemented in. Is there an explanation for this? Or do you know any other applications that's better suited.

Notice how it doesn't work here as well:

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/D3vzZ/

Answer (score 0):

It's because you forgot to include the `simplecart` script in your `jsbin`:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simplecartjs/3.0.5/simplecart.min.js"></script>
```